# How to integrate a function w.r.t time; i.e 'y' is an array and values of time(t) is varying from 1 to 3000

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, integration

How do I integrate a function `f(y)` w.r.t time; i.e `'y'` is an array of 3000 values and values of `time(t)` is varying from 1 to 3000. So, I need 3000 values after integrating `f(y)`.
Integration would be indefinite and the integral values must be without `'x'` and `'C'(Constant)`.
This is a part of my code:

```
k12 = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(3000)])
I1 = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(3000)])
m12 = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(3000)])
_k12 = [-x for x in k12]
_m12 = [-x for x in m12]

k21 = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(3000)])
I2 = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(3000)])
m21 = np.array([random.random() for _ in range(3000)])
_k21 = [-x for x in k21]
_m21 = [-x for x in m21]

k12_I1 = [i / j for i, j in zip(k12, I1)]
m12_I1 = [i / j for i, j in zip(m12, I1)]
_k12_I1 = [i / j for i, j in zip(_k12, I1)]
_m12_I1 = [i / j for i, j in zip(_m12, I1)]

k21_I2 = [i / j for i, j in zip(k21, I2)]
m21_I2 = [i / j for i, j in zip(m21, I2)]
_k21_I2 = [i / j for i, j in zip(_k21, I2)]
_m21_I2 = [i / j for i, j in zip(_m21, I2)]

X1_x = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Temp/X1_x.csv"))
X2 = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Temp/X2.csv"))
X2_diff = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Temp/X2_diff.csv"))

X3_ = ((k12*X1_x)-(I1*X2_diff)+(m12*X2))/k12
```

I need X3_ but since the integral values are of the form constant*x, so it gives an error:

```
'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float''
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you we need a [ReprEx]

Comment: Try converting all your arrays to `np.float64`. Because it looks like Pandas read from CSV arrays as integer arrays, but you need float for computations. If you have some integer array `X` then to convert it to float do `X = X.astype(np.float64)`. Does it help?

Comment: 1) I have a csv file 'X2' with 3000 values in it (all float).                                             (2) Using this csv file I had to calculate the value of 'X1' by the relation:
                                              derivative X1 =X2
                                          or integral X2 = X1                                                           (3) Since all values of X2 are constants so its integral was of the form ax+C        
(4) Now these 'x' & 'C' were recognized by python as letters and not symbols.        (5) Thus, I could not calculate the 3000 values of X1.

Comment: Your specific error `'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float''` says that you're trying to multiply integer array by floating number. That's why I said that conversion of integers to floats will help to fix this specific error. Regarding other problems - the easiest way for us to help you is for you to give us minimal reproducible example. It means that you have to provide everything what's needed to create same error on our side (our computers), only then we can help you. Give us minimal code but fully executable that gives this error. Also give us CSVs, just few lines.

Comment: https://github.com/peelwan010/CSV-and-Code.git

1) This csv file value must be integrated to get the values of X1.csv.
2) The picture that I've attached is the relation between all the values and it must be used to get the values of "X3".

Comment: @peelwan010 Can you also put `X1_x.csv` and `X2_diff.csv` into your github repository? You're using them in your code above, it means you already have it. The main idea is that you should give us everything that is needed to fully reproduce your problem, your error.

Comment: I've added them to the repository.
Thank you!

Comment: @peelwan010 Inside your X1.csv file there are values like `12345*x` later you use X1 inside `((k12*X1_x)-(I1*X2_diff)+(m12*X2))/k12`, what this expression should give you? Can't you just replace `12345*x` with `12345`? So that there is no `*x` symbol? Numpy allows only numerical computations, no symbolical computations. So you have to figure out yourself how to do only-numerical computations, how to replace `*x` etc. You have to think this way - I want to do some symbolical computations, but I have only numerical Numpy, what should I do by myself in my mind to use only numerics.

Comment: This is where I am stuck! Aren't there any scientific python libraries or modules like odeint that can compute these integrals? Or is there any way (in python) so that python reads this * x as a symbol of integral and not a letter?
Because here I am trying to take the indefinite integral of a float which equals to a*x+C; a = float itself, x = any integer (that we have to get ourselves), C = constant

Comment: @peelwan010 There are symbolical libraries like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/), very advanced and well suitable for your case. But also you can do just Numpy numerics as a helper tool when doing all symbolics in your mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230704/discussion-between-peelwan010-and-arty).

Answer (score 2):

There are symbolical libraries that totally suit your task, like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/) - very advanced symbolical library. You can use it.

Numpy library is doing only numerical computations, no symbolics, you have to do all symbolics in your mind.

As I understood in your final X3 you have sum of two terms, one of kind `Val1 * x` another is of kind `Val2`, i.e. `X3 = Val1 * x + Val2`. Then you can split your `X3` into two parts (here Val1 is X3_x and Val2 is X3_c):

```
X3_x = k12*X1/k12
X3_c = (-(I1*X2_diff)+(m12*X2))/k12
```

Later to compute whole X3 for some given fixed value of `x` you just do in Python `X3 = X3_x * x + X3_c`.

Also you have to process your CSVs in such a way that your final arrays contain only floats, no symbolics, `*x` removed everywhere, i.e. do:

```
X1_rd = np.array([e.strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('*x', '') for e in pd.read_csv(r"X1_x.csv")]).astype(np.float64)
X2_rd = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"X2.csv")).astype(np.float64)
X2_diff_rd = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"X2_diff.csv")).astype(np.float64)
```

[Full final corrected code](https://tio.run/##rVZLbuNGEN3zFAUbiLoViuZvsjCgbBIEEIKsEgQUBE2DFltWj/kbkrKprHKWnCNnmEPMRZzq5p8WFcWIbEHNqvfqVVV3l5SeikMSO6@vIkqTrID4GKUn8HOIU602ZX4cJFHzFPPiJcmeSoUpG2uKGDTgfxo0tsgv0jApQvFgpCe5Uu6w0LQny4YlKhh@lvknsqkUjOqDUNgnGTAQsZR@5MQxTZNuqbay3sOK3ifGxkkuSgUtJRR9EhJdgEQKoj3Z70p69a6co/eJsXGSg1JtS5V6ARIpiNxVNtoiAXfwSQGFjgvE/iFSgkAdVla9Oddxoo7DrhZiPSV2tRTracn9Y6PNmCjKtpBk19twHSfqOOxqIdZTYldLsZ6WliZ5wYasqqc6RPUnawx135CmWO5/ZWl41lhfsD6Uu0MidpxUHjQ@85BQ3dUznob@ji9/8sOc047tTrLdabaGM6jeclxloiSbjalbuqmbW510mVFdg9ELcfLP6uNcutWD4pTyZfLwie8KFMj5LokDZqKI1Npg7K1Wr@wtWhekgdAGbHVgqwU7A7CFoffJMSsOqm0K42BArV6ZFbqB0AbsdGCnBVsDsIOhbyHkMcmLjLR5UGVOMxEXZPb1z7/gF9UweZAiHsA@S6L6mwCe/fDIc0j28LMOX/6Gb2B1v5hheals/WymVVHUI22DSiU6dKGvlM3ozSnpNXU1maTXvuh1LnrdaS@6vdGxKPHUlnjvSwff7nZLz3bjRRQH8BDqIdRzAOOC56rqG/iobO@NZxj497aZawy7xrBrzGDtwgt@hbb9hflbVTgnuq4PgBEkqG381kHWPeVhjkBu6vJ@FM8iF0kM93DTc2OfAvQEnKx1rzoot7CKC/6Y@YWEY/aeDS8HHsMPmICpMixxZcmNwM88NX49RQ9JSGbljAJaRWUVdRRO5Apb3yUsUMizWBYMRg438NjiQKNGfdfJbDPTYTbrGbZjw7ysLGoscjkT0wC9fsB2@TPJblCmNHB5g@PR8HN5xWXR@zDxi@9cqnn2KI0R3a7IU9xA7Pf/EkBhLkTBTpwbgKo/7fyzxvPPOztzVTWXSCqZCWZdyzRd/Q44myw6pmkr6zxpZU1zoiml6JKSvPxychCiMp17Fl0QKT@vy6Pfkqjy2JTeKZDmOUyeY3xAvLRJy05Gkdwhs@U1Sm/76DA/DNsU5VB6m@X/@pI3rvpZnu9EeuruHTrUbK9@@NcYXqbSvoTQjx4CH8p7tBDTcFy@@ECb2zsMZHw@@gHZ62DqYPWGh1AdVxr5qacxl2FiUTCFE/EjOeacHWOxS4K6CzoOQT9loYjbtlTjpDdL6mS6OWIbHzBLW6o2FUtZxFl3pPzokvxzVuDCXvgfcZ@oDj58D6Z2W8rVskIbuVLIUQKtUgUbgE51ddQDk8U16E4dPdUQq2ZYDcRktNfXfwA)

Comment: Thank you so much the code is running perfectly!!
Can you please just explain what is happening here:

    X1_rd = np.array([e.strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('*x', '') for e in pd.read_csv(r"X1_x.csv")]).astype(np.float64)
    X2_rd = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"X2.csv")).astype(np.float64)
    X2_diff_rd = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"X2_diff.csv")).astype(np.float64)

Comment: @peelwan010 I just converted all 3 CSVs to float numbers. First CSV needed extra stuff - removing `[`, `]`, `*x` from it. Afterwards I split X3 into two parts `X3 = X3_x * x + X3_c` and computed them separately. All symbolical computations you have to do in your mind, Numpy is doing just numerical part.

Comment: Okay @Arty, so you removed     *x from the csv?

Comment: @peelwan010 Removed  all of `[`, `]` and `*x` from readed CSV. You don't have to edit CSV yourself, my code is doing all removal on flight.

Comment: But @Arty I needed that     '*x' in my X3 results so that in the future if I get the value of     'x', I'll just multiply all those X3 values by x. Will it be possible?

Comment: @peelwan010 I splited X3 into two parts X3_x and X3_c, those two parts mean that `X3 = X3_x * x + X3_c` so X3_x is multiplier by `x` and X3_c is constant. In order to compute full X3 you have to provide value for concrete `x`, then you just compute X3 as `X3 = X3_x * x + X3_c`, thats it.

Comment: In which line have you mentioned this?

Comment: @peelwan010 In my answer above. Also it is alright if some details about the answer are mentioned only inside comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.integrate import cumulative_trapezoid

# For all the values in columns

x = df["Time"][:df.shape[0]]   # column 1
y = df["Current"][:df.shape[0]]   # column 2

# Making the function for integration
integral = cumulative_trapezoid(y, x, initial=0)

df.loc[:, "Integral_soc"] = integral
```

Answer (score 0):

First, import `cumulative_trapezoid`

```py
from scipy.integrate import cumulative_trapezoid
```

For all the values in columns

```py
x = df["Time"][:df.shape[0]]   
y = df["Current"][:df.shape[0]]
```

Making the function for integration

```py
integral = cumulative_trapezoid(y, x, initial=0)

df.loc[:, "Integral_soc"] = integral
```